# Open excel and csv files using tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I have a folder with csv and txt files and excel files which i'm able to browse using a file explorer. But when i click on them, none open up.

Comment: How do you browse using a file explorer, please explain how and what is the code you used.

Comment: there's no proper context or explanation to your question

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for opening files with their default programs

```
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *  # import needed modules
from tkinter import filedialog
tk = Tk()
tk.geometry('500x400')  # make tkinter window


def openanyfile():
    fd = filedialog.askopenfilename()  # make function for
    webbrowser.open(fd)                # opening files


btn = Button(text="open file", command=openanyfile)  # make a button to 
btn.pack()                                           # call the function
tk.mainloop()  # update loop
```